# Write to file by increment the number

Tags: python, regex, list, file-io

I have a file and need to increment the digit in the file and save to another file, and it will keep on increment. The code I have written is absolutely working except for one condition. The file2 has to increase by one and keeps adding one if the last digit exist in the file2

Last digit of file2 (output) increments only one time but need to increment infinite till execution stop

After the 3rd execution still output 5.1:1 rather than 5.1:2
Alternate way also appreciated

```
import re
import os
rx = r'(?<=:)(\d*)$'
rex = r'(?<=:)(\d+)$'
with open('file1','r') as fh:
    fh_n = fh.read()
    with open('file2', 'a+') as fw:
        x = re.sub(rx , lambda x: str(int(x.group(0)) + 1) if len(x.group(1)) else "0", fh_n, 1, re.M)
        fw.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET) 
        if x in fw.read():
           y = re.sub(rex , lambda x: str(int(x.group(0)) + 1) , x, 1, re.M)
           fw.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)  
           fw.write(y)
        else:
           fw.write(x)
```

file1

```
    firefox 5.1:
          chrome 5.0:
```

file2 ( Expected output is below )

After 3 times execution

```
    firefox 5.1:0
          chrome 5.0:
    firefox 5.1:1
          chrome 5.0:
    firefox 5.1:2
          chrome 5.0:
```

Comment: You need to search for the *last* occurrence of the regexp in `fw`, and increment the number.

Comment: second loop doing that, y = re.sub(rex , lambda x: str(int(x.group(0)) + 1) , x, 1, re.M). but only 2 time its incrementing not infinite, 3rd,4th .. time  i got the same out as in second time execution

Comment: There's no loop, it's just a single `if`.

Comment: yes, logic is if x is in the file2 then it has to increment. are you saying need to do one loop on fw instead of x

Comment: You're never getting the value of the number `file2`. `x` is always the incremented value from `file1`. But `file1` never changes.

Comment: But if you search for the last match for the regexp in `file2`, you'll find `chrome 5.0:`, not `firfox 5.1:1`.

Comment: x in fw.read(), fw is reading the file2. So is there any alternate way to write the code

Comment: Look at what's happening. `re.sub` changes `firfox 5.1:` to `firfox 5.1:0`. Then you check if that's in `file2`. If it is, you increment `x` to `firfox 5.1:1`, and append that to `file2`. The next time you do exactly the same thing. There's nothing that finds the number in `file2` and increments that, you're always starting from `file1`, which doesn't change.

Comment: Can you overwrite `file1` with the new value of `x`? That would solve the problem easily.

Comment: no, i don't want to overwrite file1